# Unable to Autowire the MessageSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

> I have a class **StudentWithAddress** which is getting **binded** with the values filled in a form. I have **autowired** a **MessageSource** in it. but i am getting **NullPointerException** while using it.

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>Spring Try App</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>front-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>front-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

front-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- Now i will use annotation based controller and mapping. Therefore i wont be needing a 
         handler bean declaration and the controller bean declaration here.
     <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean name="/helloMessagePage" class="com.manya.spring.HelloMessageController"/> -->


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.manya.spring.modelattribute, com.manya.spring"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.manya.springmvc.aspect.LoggingAspect"/>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/strings.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="vieResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

StudentWithAddress.java :

```
package com.manya.spring.modelattribute;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSourceAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class StudentWithAddress {

    public StudentWithAddress()
    {
        System.out.println("from the constructor of the StudentWithAddress");
    }

    private String name;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    //This tells the spring the size constraint on the hobby field.
    @Size(min=2,max=15)
    private String hobby;

    private Date dob;
    private Address address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }
    public void setHobby(String hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void usingMessageSourse()
    {
        System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage(name, null, null));
    }

}
```

ModelAtributeContinuedController.java :

```
package com.manya.spring.modelattribute;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/studentWithAddressAdmission")
public class ModelAttributeContinuedController {

    @InitBinder
    public void nameCustomeEditor(WebDataBinder binder)
    {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "name", new CustomNameEditor());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/enterDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView admissionForm()
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("StudentWithAddressClassDetails");
        return mv;
    }

    //the valid annotation tells spring that only when its auto data binding, it should put 
    //validation checks on the StudentWithAddress. if its not doing data binding, then the 
    //validation must not be done.
    @RequestMapping(value="/studentClassDetails" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView details(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student1") StudentWithAddress student,BindingResult result)
    {
        //If any error was raised during data binding
        //the following code will be executed.
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("StudentWithAddressClassDetails");
            return mv;
        }
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("StudentWithAddressClassDetailsSubmitted");
        student.usingMessageSourse();
        return mv;
    }


}
```

> In the details() method of ModelAttributeContinuedController.java, when i am making call student.usingMessageSource(), I am getting following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.manya.spring.modelattribute.StudentWithAddress.usingMessageSourse(StudentWithAddress.java:61)
    at com.manya.spring.modelattribute.ModelAttributeContinuedController.details(ModelAttributeContinuedController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

> I tried implementing the same functionality using MessageSourceAware, but there also i was getting same Exception.

Comment: Have you debugged the code in your IDE? Did you set a breakpoint in `usingMessageSourse()`?  Please do that (next time, before posting the question) and tell us what you find.

Comment: Try by putting autowire="byName" in `<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">`, it should look like `<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" autowire="byName">
    autowire="byName">`

Comment: I debugged the application but its not autowiring the MessageSource. and hence when i am calling usingMessageSource() , its giving NullPointerException. @JimGarrison

Comment: I even tried implementing MessageSourceAware, but the setMessageSource callback method is not even called.